# Proving B-Min-Cost Strongly connected Subgraph is NP-Complete

Tags: np-complete, reductions

We have a strongly connected directed graph where each edge has positive integer weights. We are also given a $B \in \mathbb{N}$. Does there exist a strongly connected subgraph where sum of edge weights $\leq B$?

I'm not sure what NP-Complete problem to use. I tried subset sum, but it takes exponential time to build the graph I had in mind (yes/no tree with edge cost being the numbers in subset sum problem, and a final edge to root at end of every decision sequence). Any ideas? Is there a better NP-Complete problem to use?

Comment: I don't think it's NP-hard. If there is a negative cycle, you are done. Otherwise, compute all pairwise distances $d(u,v)$. Now simply find if there is a pair of vertices such that $d(u,v)+d(v,u) \le B$. This cycle will be the required subgraph.

Comment: There is no requirement that each edge $(u,v)$ has a backwards edge $(v,u).$

Comment: $d(u,v)$ is a distance between $u$ and $v$, i.e. the weight of the shortest path from $u$ to $v$, not the weight of the edge between them.

Comment: @Dmitry The fact that the shortest (with minimal total weight) path from $u$ to $v$ may cross other vertices means that you must keep those vertices in the subgraph (and the corresponding edges). That may increase the total weight of the strongly connected subgraph you consider.

Comment: For example, imagine the following graph: $f(u, v) = 1$, $f(v, u) = 5$, $f(v, w) = 1$, $f(w, u) = 1$, $f(w, v) = 10$. Your algorithm will determine that $d(u, v) + d(v, u) = 3$, but the sum of the weight of the edges of the subgraph contening those path will be $18$ (but the subgraph contening only $u$ and $v$ has total sum $6$).

Comment: @Nathaniel, `must keep ... the corresponding edges` - No. It's required to find a subgraph (i.e. any subset of vertices/edges, as long as for each edge their endpoints are present), not an induced subgraph (which is what you seem to have in mind).

Comment: In that case, you are right, I just thought that it was implied that the subgraph was induced.

Comment: @Nathaniel, well, maybe you are right and this is what the OP wants.

Comment: @Dmitry If the subgraph is induced, the problem is indeed NP-complete (proved by Yannakakis in 1978 https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221591501_Node-_and_Edge-Deletion_NP-Complete_Problems)